# Difference between Dispatcher and TaskSchduler

Tags: wpf, c#-5.0

In WPF both Dispatcher and taskscheduler helps to pass the value from background thread to UI thread. So really what is the difference between them.
For instance in the below code what is the actual Difference between option 1 and option 2

```
        Task<int> tsk = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(TestMethod);
        var threadSchedulder = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        //Option 1
        tsk.ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                SetText(tsk.Result);
            }, threadSchedulder);

        //Option 2
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            SetText(tsk.Result);
        });
```

Comment: `Task<int> tsk = Task<int>.Factory...` - dude, please use `var`, C# is not java.

Comment: They have nothing in common.  TaskScheduler.FromSynchronizationContext() knows how to use SynchronizationContext.Current which knows how to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to get the task to run on the UI thread of a WPF app.  The advantage of using TaskScheduler is that it still works when it your code doesn't run in a WPF app.  The disadvantage is that it will fail to do its job when you don't create the Task on the UI thread.

Comment: @HansPassant In a practical sense (from the OP's "consumer" code) standpoint, they're pretty much the same..

Comment: in wpf, use dispatcher for better clarity of your intentions, since it is the recommended way

Answer (score 0):

Both will do almost the same thing and  will have its own advantages.

•   **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() :** Just to Updating something on the UI thread **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** is the best option. Typically this is done to update some UI controls with the results of some operation that was executed on a background thread. The Dispatcher.Invoke call will block until this operation completes. We should not execute lengthy operations over here.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>{myLabel.Text = "myText"});
```

•   **Task.Factory.StartNew() :** It is useful when compose multiple tasks together. This makes scheduling work that's dependent on previous tasks far simpler, since you can use Task.WaitAll/Task.WaitAny, as well as continuations.

Comment: question was taskscheduler vs dispatcher